# WPF: How do I tell the XAML file where to find my UserControl?

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls, namespaces

I have created an UserControl and I want to create another one which inherits from the first one. I understand that this supposed to work like this:

```
<myFirstUserControl x:Class="myAssembly.mySecondUserControl" ...
```

Now VS tells me "The type 'myFirstUserControl' was not found."

So I tried

```
<local:myFirstUserControl x:Class="myAssembly.mySecondUserControl" ...
```

Now VS tells me "The namespace prefix 'local' is not defined."

So I tried

```
<myAssembly.myFirstUserControl x:Class="myAssembly.mySecondUserControl" ...
```

Now VS tells me "Nested types are not supported."

How do I tell the XAML file where to find my UserControl?

Answer (score 0):

Magically solved itself?!

I had to put

```
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:myAssembly"
```

into the XAML. I guess I wasn't recognized until a Cleaned the build.